# How to attach screenshot to protractor's HTML report?

Tags: protractor, test-report

In my `protractor` project, i am trying to take an screenshot, and attach it to my `html` report. The process of taking screenshot is happening in an `After` ***hook***, as below:

```
import {  Status,After, HookScenarioResult} from 'cucumber';
import {browser} from 'protractor';
import { async } from 'q';

After(async  (scenario:HookScenarioResult)=> {

    if(scenario.result.status===Status.FAILED){
        const screenshot = await browser.takeScreenshot();
        this.attach(screenshot,"image/png");
    }
});
```

But in the line `this.attach(screenshot,"image/png");`, it complains with:

```
TypeError: this.attach is not a function
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Refer my answer in below post:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25115272/cucumber-html-report-with-protractor/55858210#55858210

Comment: Did you ever solve this? Could you accept an answer, or add an answer yourself?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use arrow function, try using below, this worked for me:

```
After(async function (scenario){
    if(scenario.result.status=== Status.FAILED){
        const screenShotFail= await browser.takeScreenshot();
        this.attach(screenShotFail, "image/png");
    }
})
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to handle it yourself in the code. There are external node packages to handle it beautifully.

You may use packages like [protractor-html-reporter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-html-reporter).

## How to use

- Using with protractor conf.js file

  //HTMLReport called once tests are finished

  ```
  onComplete: function() {
       var browserName, browserVersion;
       var capsPromise = browser.getCapabilities();

       capsPromise.then(function (caps) {
          browserName = caps.get('browserName');
          browserVersion = caps.get('version');

          var HTMLReport = require('protractor-html-reporter');

          testConfig = {
              reportTitle: 'Test Execution Report',
              outputPath: './',
              screenshotPath: './screenshots',
              testBrowser: browserName,
              browserVersion: browserVersion,
              modifiedSuiteName: false,
              screenshotsOnlyOnFailure: true
          };
          new HTMLReport().from('xmlresults.xml', testConfig);
      });
   }
  ```
- In order to obtain screenshots on failure you can use this piece of code (you have to put it in onPrepare). The directory with screenshots must be in the same location as html report file (e.g. html file is in report directory so screenshots files must be in directory /report/screenshots/).

```
var fs = require('fs-extra');
fs.emptyDir('screenshots/', function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
```

`jasmine.getEnv().addReporter({
    specDone: function(result) {
        if (result.status == 'failed') {
            browser.getCapabilities().then(function (caps) {
                var browserName = caps.get('browserName');

                browser.takeScreenshot().then(function (png) {
                    var stream = fs.createWriteStream('screenshots/' + browserName + '-' + result.fullName+ '.png');
                    stream.write(new Buffer(png, 'base64'));
                    stream.end();
                });
            });
        }
    }
});`

Comment: Please provide the reason for downvote.